# send data form file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use the below code to send data for image file with js and they works great but when I add

```
 var image = document.getElementById("img_book").files[0];
 var form = new FormData(); 
 form.append("image", image);
```

I get error with append.

This my code

```
$("#publish").click(function() {
   var x = event.target.responseText;
   document.getElementById("book_id").setAttribute("value",x);
   var image = document.getElementById("img_book").files[0];
   var form = new FormData(); 
   form.append("image", image);

   var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
   var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
   var cat = document.getElementById("cat").value;
   var sub_cat = document.getElementById("sub_cat").value;
   var tags = document.getElementById("tags").value;
   var lang = document.getElementById("lang").value;
   var privacy = document.getElementById("privacy").value;
   var id = document.getElementById("book_id").value;
   //if((title !== "") && (desc !== "") && (cat !== "") && (sub_cat !== "") && (lang !== "") && (privacy !== "")) {
     $.ajax({
       url: "ajax/upload/publish.php",
       method  : "POST",
       data : {'form' : form ,'title' : title,'desc' : desc, 'cat' : cat , 'sub_cat' : sub_cat , 'tags' : tags , 'lang' : lang , 'privacy' : privacy , 'id' : id},
       cache: true,
       success : function(data) {
         if(data.status == 'success'){
          window.location.replace("http://localhost/book/book.php?id=" + id);
        }else if(data.status == 'error'){
          alert("Error on query!");
        }
      }
    });
   //}
 });
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Post html please. If the structure is what I think it is you have made your code overly complicated.

Comment: @ksealey my html code just inputs and form

Comment: @MouradKa I understand, but if all your elements you are getting the values from are in the form, you are writing quite a bit of extra code. I'm trying to save you some time and debugging frustrations in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append all the parameters to the formdata object, or more easily pass the form containing the data to the from data constructor.

Then pass the formdata object alone in the request, also contentType and processData has to be set to false.

Comment: In your ajax call add the properties `processData: false, contentType: false,`

Comment: If all the data is in a form just do `var form = new FormData($("#formid")[0]);` then `data: form,`